# Gradient-like color on model imported from blender

Tags: c++, c, qt, opengl, blender

I imported a model from blender to a C array and displayed it with openGL (glew) under Qt.

I have an embedded resource vertex and fragment shader too. I managed to make the vertex shader work and display correctly the model, but now I'd like to give it a gradient-like effect (it's a simple box, but I'm planning to write on it somehow, so I need to make it look decent).

How may I accomplish this? A texture with blender? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple linear gradient you could just add a line in your vertex shader that sets `gl_FrontColor` to some (vec4) value, e.g. depending on the vertex's Y-coordinate. And in the fragment shader you set the `gl_FragColor` to `gl_Color` (or multiply it by `gl_Color` if you're also texturing the object).